# How Kryo serializer allocates buffer in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, kryo

Please help to understand how Kryo serializer allocates memory for its buffer.

My Spark app fails on a collect step when it tries to collect about 122Mb of data to a driver from workers.

```
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Buffer overflow. Available: 0, required: 57197
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.require(Output.java:138)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.writeBytes(Output.java:220)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.writeBytes(Output.java:206)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultArraySerializers$ByteArraySerializer.write(DefaultArraySerializers.java:29)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultArraySerializers$ByteArraySerializer.write(DefaultArraySerializers.java:18)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObjectOrNull(Kryo.java:549)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultArraySerializers$ObjectArraySerializer.write(DefaultArraySerializers.java:312)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultArraySerializers$ObjectArraySerializer.write(DefaultArraySerializers.java:293)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:568)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializerInstance.serialize(KryoSerializer.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
```

This exception is shown after I've increased the driver memory to 3Gb and executor memory to 4Gb and increased buffer size for kryoserializer (I'm using Spark 1.3)

```
conf.set('spark.kryoserializer.buffer.mb', '256')
conf.set('spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max', '512')
```

I think I've set buffer to be big enough, but my spark app keeps crashing. 
How can I check what objects are using Kryo buffer on a executor?
Is there way to clean it up?

Comment: Looks like the problem is that Spark 1.3 doesn't have property `spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max` - it has `spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max.mb` . I'm testing the app now with the correct property set.

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto did my answer helped you with your issue?

Comment: @ vvladymyrov It didn't, I get this problem every time I run NaiveBayes fit on a big dataset where the features are in the form of SparseVectors with millions of features

Comment: No one is answering the question "how can I check what objects are using Kryo [...]?" :(

Answer (score 16):

In my case, the problem was using the wrong property name for the max buffer size.

[Up to Spark version 1.3](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/configuration.html#compression-and-serialization) the property name is `spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max.mb` - it has "`.mb`" in the end. But I used property name from [Spark 1.4 docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#compression-and-serialization) - `spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max` .

As a result spark app was using the default value - 64mb. And it was not enough for the amount of data I was processing.

After I fixed the property name to `spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max.mb` my app worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

Use `conf.set('spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max.mb', 'val')` to set `kryoserializer` buffer and keep in mind `val` should be less than 2048 otherwise you will get some error again indicating buffer should be less than 2048MB

Answer (score 4):

Solution is to setup `spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max` to `1g`  in `spark-default.conf` and restarting spark services

This at least worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Now `spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max.mb` is deprecated

> WARN spark.SparkConf: The configuration key
>   'spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max.mb' has been deprecated as of Spark
>   1.4 and and may be removed in the future. Please use the new key 'spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max' instead.

You should rather use:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
val conf = new SparkConf()
conf.set("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "val")
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is old but for Spark (version 2.4.0), if you're looking to change the 'spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max' property go to,

> /etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf

and add/change

> spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max = "*value you desire*".

Reference: [Eli's Blog](https://www.devtech101.com/2016/05/26/to-increase-spark-kyroserializer-buffer-max/)

Answer (score 1):

I am using spark 1.5.2 and I had the same issue. Setting `spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max.mb` to 256 fixed it.